# Topology in an underlying set of $X.$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $S$ be a subset $X$ fixed. Show that
>
> $$\tau= \{A \cup (B \cap S) \mid A,B \text{ open at } X  \}$$
>
> determines another topology on the underlying subset of $X.$

**My attempt**

Using that $A \cup (B \cap S)= (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup S)$

where we see that the union and intersection of subsets of $\tau$ remains in $\tau$ and with it we see that it is a topology.

I am new to this, I would appreciate it if you could tell me if the test is correct or failing, because you would give me some hint to learn topology.

Thank you.

Comment: A specific question: do I have to analyze all the cases of subsets of $\tau$ to see what is topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$, you must show three things: $\varnothing,X\in\tau$; for any $U,V\in\tau$, $U\cap V\in\tau$ ($\tau$ is *closed under intersection*); and for any $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$, $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$ ($\tau$ is *closed under taking arbitrary unions*).

Let $\tau_0$ be the original topology on $X$. Then by definition

$$\tau=\{G\cup(H\cap S):G,H\in\tau_0\}\;.$$

Since $\tau_0$ is a topology on $X$, we know that $\varnothing\in\tau_0$, so for each $U\in\tau_0$ we know that

$$U\cup(\varnothing\cap S)=U\cup\varnothing=U\in\tau\;;$$

this shows that $\tau_0\subseteq\tau$ and hence that $\varnothing,X\in\tau$ (since $\varnothing,X\in\tau_0$).

Now let $U,V\in\tau$; there are $G_U,H_U,G_V,H_V\in\tau_0$ such that $U=G_U\cup(H_U\cap S)$ and $V=G_V\cup(H_V\cap S)$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
U\cap V&=\big(G_U\cup(H_U\cap S)\big)\cap\big(G_V\cup(H_V\cap S)\big)\\
&=\Big(G_U\cap\big(G_V\cup(H_V\cap S)\big)\Big)\cup\Big((H_U\cap S)\cap\big(G_V\cup(H_V\cap S)\big)\Big)\\
&=(G_U\cap G_V)\cup(G_U\cap H_V\cap S)\cup(H_U\cap S\cap G_V)\cup(H_U\cap S\cap H_V\cap S)\\
&=(G_U\cap G_V)\cup(G_U\cap H_V\cap S)\cup(G_V\cap H_U\cap S)\cup(H_U\cap H_V\cap S)\\
&=(G_U\cap G_V)\cup\Big(\big((G_U\cap H_V)\cup(G_V\cap H_U)\cup(H_U\cap H_V)\big)\cap S\Big)\\
&=G\cup(H\cap S)\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $G=G_U\cap G_V$ and $H=(G_U\cap H_V)\cup(G_V\cap H_U)\cup(H_U\cap H_V)$. Both $G$ and $H$ are open in $\tau_0$, the original topology, so by $G\cup(H\cap S)\in\tau$, i.e., $U\cap V\in\tau$, and $\tau$ is therefore closed under intersection.

Finally, let $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$. For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ there are $G_U,H_U\in\tau_0$ such that $U=G_U\cup(H_U\cap S)$. Now

$$\begin{align*}
\bigcup\mathscr{U}&=\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}\big(G_U\cup(H_U\cap S)\big)\\
&=\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}G_U\cup\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}(H_U\cap S)\\
&=\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}G_U\cup\left(\left(\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}H_U\right)\cap S\right)\\
&=G\cup(H\cap S)\;,
\end{align*}$$

where

$$G=\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}G_H\quad\text{and}\quad H=\bigcup_{U\in\mathscr{U}}H_U\;.$$

Being a topology, $\tau_0$ is closed under arbitrary unions, so $G,H\in\tau_0$, and therefore by definition $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$, which is therefore also closed under arbitrary unions.

This completes the proof that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. It is the smallest topology that contains both the original topology $\tau_0$ and the set $S$; that is, $\tau_0\cup\{S\}$ is a base for $\tau$. (To see that $S\in\tau$, just observe that $S=\varnothing\cup(X\cap S)$, where $\varnothing,X\in\tau_0$.)

Comment: Excelent, thanks!

Comment: Always Great answer!(+1)

Comment: @Haus: You're welcome!